# Should I use "the" in a list of multiple subjects?

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-articles, writing-style

Which of these sentences is correct?

> The assets of the thesis are **the** parser library, tag library and external database, which can be used in other applications.

or

> The assets of the thesis are **the** parser library, **the** tag library and **the** external database, which can be used in other applications.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Shouldn't that be *the parser and tag libraries*?

Comment: .Errata corrige: You can combine the words parser library and tag library together as in : "The assets of the thesis are **the parser and tag libraries**, and the external database . . ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the second is correct, as the elements in the list are **separate/individualized** and not a compound.

Your sentence is not clear as to what "which" refers to. Fix:

*The assets of the thesis are the parser library, the tag library **[,]** and the external database, **all of** which can be used in other applications.*

Also, an Oxford comma is required in AmE before the latest element of a list (CMOS).

Comment: You're right about the _Chicago Manual of Style_ rule on serial commas. But on the other hand, in most instances, a serial comma is prohibited in AmE before the last element of a list (Associated Press Stylebook). Both of these styles have numerous supporters in U.S. publishing.